# Grails - Fatal error running tests: Lcom/overzealous/remark/Remark

Tags: java, grails, testing, jenkins

Grails version: 2.3.4
JDK: Oracle 1.7.0_40

When running "grails test-app" on a completely clean grails project for the first time, I get the following error:

```
    Fatal error running tests: Lcom/overzealous/remark/Remark; (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/overzealous/remark/Remark;
    at TestApp$_run_closure1.doCall(TestApp:99)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at TestApp$_run_closure1.doCall(TestApp.groovy:32)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.overzealous.remark.Remark
    ... 28 more

Error |
Fatal error running tests: Lcom/overzealous/remark/Remark;
.Tests FAILED 
|
 - view reports in ... target/test-reports
Error |
Error executing script TestApp: Lcom/overzealous/remark/Remark; (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/overzealous/remark/Remark;
    at TestApp$_run_closure1.doCall(TestApp:99)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at TestApp$_run_closure1.doCall(TestApp.groovy:32)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.overzealous.remark.Remark
    ... 28 more
```

When I build it the second time, the failure is gone. Having a completely fresh project happens on our Jenkins more than once... When a build job for a grails project is automatically created, the first build is always yellow due to this failure. Whilst not deleting the workspace for the following builds, the error doesn't occur again for this job.

Does anybody have an idea, why the class cannot be found?

Comment: I have the same problem after adding the markdown plugin as a dependency. Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: No i never fixed it. It's good to know, that it's  the markdown plugin. I just didn't invest time into this, because it's not a real problem. Thanks!

Comment: same problem. I guess we better find a replacement for that plugin if nobody was able to resolve this issue

Comment: I created my own Service using the [markdown4j](https://github.com/jdcasey/markdown4j) library, because i needed the **extensibility** in order to integrate attributes into the generated HTML tags. It works really fine.

Comment: @jan.mueller how can i use it? is it on any maven global repo or something like that?